# Why can't I remove specific patterns from php string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
\n\nVerse 1\nA love of nature I have found,\nIn the eyes of my beloved hound.\nThe sweet smell of the wildflowers,\nAs we explore the bright green bowers.\n\nVerse 2\nWe travel the hills and meadows so free,\nThe warmth of the sun caressing me.
```

I want to remove the `\n\nVerse x\n` patterns (where `x` is changing) but I can't figure out how.

I tried replacing it with a while loop that looks for them using strpos but I always get an error like Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset.

I expect to get a string like:

```
\nA love of nature I have found,\nIn the eyes of my beloved hound.\nThe sweet smell of the wildflowers,\nAs we explore the bright green bowers.\nWe travel the hills and meadows so free,\nThe warmth of the sun caressing me.
```

Comment: There's no `:` after `Verse x`. Take that out of the pattern.

Comment: '/\nVerse \d+\n/' ?? still doesn't work

Comment: Works here: https://ideone.com/DIS865

Comment: Does your string have literal `\n` or are those newline characters?

Comment: If it's literal, you need to use `\\\n` in the regexp.

Comment: Thank you, \\\n fixed it. I don't really know how to use \,\\,\\\ etc

Comment: ChatGPT content is [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) here because it is notoriously unreliable. I have removed it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 levels of quoting/escaping happening, once for the PHP string, and then again for the regex engine.

To write a literal `\n` string with single quotes, `'\n'` will suffice, but is not *completely* correct since `\\` and `\'` are still valid escapes even in single-quoted strings. So it should *technically* be `'\\n'`. [Yes, this is a bit pedantic, but stay with me.]

Now if we give the literal string `\n` in a regular expression PCRE will interpolate that to a literal line break, so we need to actually give it `\\n`, which means we need to escape *both* backslashes as `'\\\\n`.

The given solution of `'\\\n'` works because an unpaired escape is left as-is, but when you eventually mix up your quotes you'll get that literal line break back, or some similar buggy behaviour.

All that said, if you find yourself writing long chains of `\\\\\\\\\` you should consider that you might be missing a useful function, eg: [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote).

So your might look something along the lines of:

```php
$nl = preg_quote('\n');
$pattern = "/${nl}Verse \d+:\${nl}";
$var = preg_replace($pattern, '', $var);
```

It's a bit clunky here, but it can be *very* useful.